# Scraping data using simple html dom and simpleXML

Tags: php, web-scraping, simplexml, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to scrape data from several links which i retrieve from a xml file. However i keep getting an error which only seem to appear on some of the news. below you can see the output i get

```
http://www.hltv.org/news/14971-rgn-pro-series-groups-drawnRGN Pro Series groups drawn

http://www.hltv.org/news/14969-k1ck-reveal-new-teamk1ck reveal new team

http://www.hltv.org/news/14968-world-championships-captains-unveiled
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in  /app/scrape.php on line 266
```

where this is line 266

```
$hltv_full_text = $hltv_deep_link->find("//div[@class='rNewsContent']", 0);
```

Full code

Scrape function

```
function scrape_hltv() {
    $hltv = "http://www.hltv.org/news.rss.php";
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($hltv);
    global $con;
    foreach($sxml->channel->item as $item)
    {
        $hltv_title = (string)$item->title;
        $hltv_link = (string)$item->link;
        $hltv_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime((string)$item->pubDate));
        echo $hltv_link;

        //if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime((string)$item->pubDate)) ==  date('Y-m-d')){
            if (strpos($hltv_title,'Video:') === false) {
                $hltv_deep_link = file_get_html($hltv_link);
                $hltv_full_text = $hltv_deep_link->find("//div[@class='rNewsContent']", 0);


                echo $hltv_title . '<br><br>';

            }
        //}


    }

}

scrape_hltv();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why it returns error: Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several occasions when `file_get_html()` returns `false`.

See the source code here:
http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/simple_html_dom.php#l79

```
if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
{
    return false;
}
```

For your link

http://www.hltv.org/news/14968-world-championships-captains-unveiled

I think it is because the content of the page is larger than `MAX_FILE_SIZE`(600 000 bytes). The page size is actually around 3 MBs.

If you want to process larger files as well you can try modified version of the function:

```
define('DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET', 'UTF-8');
define('DEFAULT_BR_TEXT', "\r\n");
define('DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT', " ");

function file_get_html_modified($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
{
    $dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);
    $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
    if (empty($contents))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
    return $dom;
}
```

... `|| strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE` was removed.

Comment: @PeterPik Do you want to process larger files as well? Or just don't want your code to crash?

Comment: hmm i just want it to process the file even though it might be bigger